# How can I read a parameter array from excel so that its values are available when stocks are initialized?

Tags: arrays, excel, parameters, anylogic

The problem:

I need to read a row of values from an excel spreadsheet into a parameter array and use these values to set the initial values of stocks.

The specifics:

a. I can successfully set the scalar parameters default values from excel using ExcelControlName.getCellNumericValue("ExcelSheetName", RowNumber, ColumnNumber).

b. Trying to set default values for array parameters with ExcelControlName.readHyperArray(DestinationArrayName,"ExcelSheetName",RowNumber, ColumnNumber, false) returns a "Cannot return a void result" error on build.

c. I can read the parameter arrays from a function called from the Agent actions "On startup:" section using ExcelControlName.readHyperArray(DestinationArrayName,"ExcelSheetName",RowNumber, ColumnNumber, false).

d. Stocks with their initial values set to the parameter array that was successfully loaded by the function are all zero even though the parameter array shows values (when run). Initial value: ParameterArrayName.

e. When I set the parameter array values through the value editor the stocks initialize correctly.

My suspicion:

I'm thinking that the issue has something to do with the internal timing within the entrails of the model generated by Anylogic such that the function to load the parameters is executed after the stocks get initial values - but that could just be the delirium caused by repeatedly smashing my forehead into the wall. But, if this is indeed the case, how can I sneak the function in earlier or, better yet, how would someone who actually knows what they're doing accomplish this?

What I'm trying to accomplish:

As a septuagenarian with lots of time on my hands and a vague recollection of dynamic modeling using Dynamo from a Systems Science program in the early seventies (and not used since), I thought I'd take a whack at age-based modeling of the COVID-19 pandemic. I wanted to see, among other things, whether establishing elder-prisons (in now vacant Club-Meds, Sandals... I'm sure) would be an economically advantageous strategy. Getting there requires dis-aggregating classic SIR approaches into age-specific chains of causality. So far, I'm at 27 age-specific parameters for eight age-groups and 24 scalar parameters. As much as I'd like to type and retype... all this data I'm really hoping there is a better way.

I must say that I am amazed at how far modeling has come in only 50 or so years and I am enthralled with Anylogic's application - even though it's a bit java-ish for me.

Thank you ever so much,

Carl Cottrell

[Equivalent parameter arrays - one with values entered in edit the other read from excel file through a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li9Yu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand but here it goes:

I understand that you have the following structure:
[image: sd structure]

and you want to initialize the stock as follows. 
[image: initialization of stock]

To do that, on the initial value of your parameter use a function that returns an HyperParameter:
[image: initialization]

the function getInitialValue should return an HyperParameter and I think this code should work for you (you have to choose RowNumber according to whatever is on your excelfile, MyDimension is the name of your dimension, and ExcelControlName is the excel in which you hold the values of the initial values of the stock)

```
HyperArray x=new HyperArray(MyDimension);
for(int i=0;i<=numColumns;i++){
    x.set(ExcelControlName.getCellNumericValue("ExcelSheetName", RowNumber, i), i);
}

return x;
```

Comment: are you related to Les Cottrell from SLAC?